# Skrollr: div flattering up and down when changing margin-top

Tags: margin, skrollr

I have a problem with Skrollr. I have a div (grey) changing its position from left to right when scrolling down. Inside the div (yellow), there's another div. I want it to stay at the same height as long as the parent div is still changing its position. I tried to do this with changing the margin-top, just like this:

```
<div id="grey" data-100="right:100%;" data-700="right:50%;">
<div id="yellow" data-100="margin-top:200px;" data-700="margin-top:800px;"</div></div>
```

[And that's what happens.](http://schlze.de/test/)
Everything would be okay, but the yellow div is flattering up and down while moving right. Is there any way to solve this without using 'position:fixed'? Thanks for help!

EDIT: On iPad it works, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser moves the yellow div up (with everything else, because it's scrolling) and slightly after that the `margin-top` animation moves it down again. The only way to get perfect results is with `fixed`.

But you can make it slightly better by disabling smooth scrolling for the yellow div. You will still see it jumping when scrolling very fast.

```
<div id="yellow" data-smooth-scrolling="off" data-100="margin-top:200px;" data-700="margin-top:800px;"</div>
```

Also I suggest using CSS transforms instead of margin.

```
<div id="yellow" data-smooth-scrolling="off" data-100="transform:translate(0, 200px);" data-700="transform:translate(0, 800px);"</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, in Firefox and Chrome it's just perfect now. In other browsers it still flatters, but not as much as before:  [link](http://www.schlze.de/test2)